# What are the earliest commentaries available on Sri Devi Bhagavatam and from which sampradaya?

Tags: devi-bhagavata-purana, reference-request

While reading through on a different topic, I came across [this](https://www.kamakotimandali.com/srividya/bhaskara.html) link, which talks about Sri Bhaskararaya, which states:

> Bhaskaracharya was born in the period between the last part of the
>   seventeenth century and the beginning of the eighteenth century. In
>   his own works, we find a mention of his birth date. He is known to
>   have completed his commentary on Sri Lalita Sahasranama in 1728
>   (Ashwina Shukla Navami) and Setubandha in 1748 (Shivaratri). Though
>   Sri Bhaskaracharya was proficient in all branches of learning, he was
>   essentially a Shakta.

And this:

> It was he who popularized the Devi Bhagavata Mahapurana and
>   the Adbhutakaanda - the eighth Kaanda of Ramayana.

It is not clear if he actully wrote a commentary on the Devi Bhagavatam itself.

There is also not much information available online or with my vaadhyaars (vedic scholars who officiate as priests in rituals) who are from the Kanchi mutt regarding actual commentaries

So, are there any commentaries on the Sri Devi Bhagavatam available from any sampradaya? I am not looking for where the text might be referenced (those might be numerous, it doesn't matter) but a sampradayic work which gives an actual commentary on the book itself.